# React-Native fetch post to lumen/laravel returns MethodNotAllowed(405) but postman works

Tags: laravel, react-native, fetch, postman, lumen

I know this questions have been asked before but non of the answers worked for me.

I am working with React Native and sending API's to Lumen-Backend and i realised that all POST request to LUMEN returns 405 error. Tested it with Postman and it works very fine.
 Tried using fetch and axios but they all return 405 errors. Find codes Bellow

[Postman request working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGNzL.png)

**FETCH CALL**

```
    const BASE_URL = 'http://192.168.43.232/2019/betbank_api/public/api/';
    const url = '/app/auth/login/'
    const endPoint = BASE_URL.concat(url);

    const data ={ email: 'okeke', password:'passs' }

        async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {

          const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST', 
            cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/text'
            },

            body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
          });
          return await response.text(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
        }

        postData(endPoint, { email: 'okeke', password:'passs' })
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `response.json()` call
            alert(data)
          });
```

Also tried implementing the same thing using AXIOS
but ir returns same 405 error. **Find Axios code bellow**

```
  axios.post(endPoint, data, {
    headers: { 
      'Accept': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    }
  }).then( (response)=>{

    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
    alert(JSON.stringify(response.data))
  }

  ).catch( (error)=>{
    console.log(error)
    alert(error)
  })
```

Find the **Lumen Route - API bellow**

```
        $router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {

                $router->post('/app/auth/login', 'AppUserController@postLogin');


            });
```

FInd the method postLogin Bellow

```
        class AppUserController extends Controller
        {

            protected $jwt;

            public function __construct(JWTAuth $jwt)
            {
                $this->jwt = $jwt;
            }

            public function postLogin(Request $request)
                {

                    $email = $request->input('email');



                    $this->validate($request, [
                        'email'    => 'required|email|max:255',
                        'password' => 'required',
                    ]);

                    try {

                        if (! $token = $this->jwt->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {

                            return response()->json(['status'=>'error','data'=> 'Invalid username and passowrd'], 401);
                        }

                    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

                        return response()->json(['token_expired'], 500);

                    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

                        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], 500);

                    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

                        return response()->json(['token_absent' => $e->getMessage()], 500);

                    }

                    return response()->json(compact('token'));
                }


        }
```

Everythings seems in order but somehow, neither fetch or axios would work when i use the POST method. 
But if i change it to GET method, the error stops but the issue would now be how to get the data's been posted from the APP.

**QUESTION**
Why would all *Post request* from my App (React Native) be returning 405 from Lumen/Laravel

Comment: Further research shows that its a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) issue which i have tried the following CORS methods which did not work for me.


Configured new Middlewares  on **bootstrap/app**

`App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class,` 
`\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,`
`\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class` 

Non of this worked for me

Comment: have you solved this issue bcs Im lost in this issue to... same for me  postman works